# ServiceController.Start() don't reach "Running" status

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

As the title says, I'm trying to start a service created at run-time, but I always end-up getting the 'timeout' exception, as the service status does not change to Running and hangs on Starting forever.

Here's my StartService() function:

```
private void StartService()
{
    ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
    try
    {                    
         SaveProject();
         if (!CheckServiceExist(serviceName))
             CreateService();
         TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30000);
         service.Start();
         service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Trace.Writeline(ex.ToString());
     }
}
```

I can confirm that CreateService() is doing what is supposed to do flawlessy.

When I call from Visual Studio (2013) the first time, it occurs as described. BUT, when I run again, it works like a charm! When I run outside Visual Studio, it hangs on Starting and I can't either Start or Stop it through Windows Task Manager nor Windows Services.

I'm using WCF and Windows Service, and the StartService() is called from a button Command, if that helps at all. Thanks in advance.

Comment: tried debugging to work out why the first call from visual studio fails?
With the 2nd attempt from visual studio working its quite possibly visual studio is caching some data. Suggestion: increase the timeout

Comment: Yep, I've tried both your suggestions. Debugging only gives me a message saying something about failing to get a response in time. I've too increased the timeout, but no luck: the service hangs on "StartPending".

Comment: Is this a service you have coded and you have a problem with the implementation of the "Start Button" click, or you have a problem with starting a pre-existing service programmatically. If it is the prior, were you able to reproduce the issue with a simple "Hello, World!" service and start the service from services.msc?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx) page.

Under **Setting Service Status** you will find "*If a service takes a little while to start up, it might be helpful to report a Start Pending status*". There is a detailed explanation how to tell the windows service manager that your service is still in startup process and avoid a timeout.

```
// Update the service state to Start Pending.
ServiceStatus serviceStatus = new ServiceStatus();
serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_START_PENDING;
serviceStatus.dwWaitHint = 100000;
SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);
```

But this will only help if the timeout is really the problem on your service implementation.

Comment: Well, I don't believe the timeout is the problem, but I'll try anyway. Be right back with an update,

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but as I've thought, nothing changes after applying the solution above. The problem isn't the timeout itself (this is just a symptom), but instead the service not changing from StartPending to Running.

Comment: Did you proof that your service leave the "OnStart" method? If the start thread is never left, the start is never finished.